# Get li items and add them to javascript obj

Tags: javascript, html

I have a list elements and I want to add the list elements to object with key value pair. I am expecting output like `phrase={1:First,2:second}` in `obj` I have tried adding elements to obj but its coming out empty.

```js
var phrase = {};
var inc = 1;
$("#menu select-li").each(function() {
  phrase[inc] = $(this).text();
  inc++;
});
console.log(phrase)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tab-pane fade show active">
  <ul class="end-info" id="menu">

    <li value="First" class="select-li First">
      <span class="caret First">&nbsp;</span>First</li>
    <ul class="nested First">
      <li value="First Report">First Report</li>
      <li value="Second Report">Second Report</li>
      <li value="Third Report">Third Report</li>
    </ul>
    <li value="second" class="select-li Second">
      <span class="caret second">&nbsp;</span>second</li>
    <ul class="nested second">
      <li value="First Report">First Report</li>
      <li value="Second Report">Second Report</li>
    </ul>
  </ul>
  <div>
```

Comment: Missing a dot prefix for class selector ....  `$("#menu .select-li")`

Comment: Have you read the jQuery `each()` function documentation? You can pass the index into the callback; you don't need to define a separate `inc` variable to iterate (note that the index will be zero-based though).

Comment: 99 times of 100 you'll get into troubles later, when you start indexing from 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What do you mean by `"#menu select-li"`? There's no tag called `<select-li>` in your code. What you really need is:

```
$("#menu .select-li").each();
```

Also, use `$(this).attr("value")` to get the contents from the `value` attribute.

The `index` will help you get the right indices.

Your HTML is also invalid. The right one will be:

```js
var phrase = {};
$("#menu .select-li").each(function(index) {
  phrase[index + 1] = $(this).attr("value");
});
console.log(phrase)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tab-pane fade show active">
  <ul class="end-info" id="menu">
    <li value="First" class="select-li First">
      <span class="caret First">&nbsp;</span>First
      <ul class="nested First">
        <li value="First Report">First Report</li>
        <li value="Second Report">Second Report</li>
        <li value="Third Report">Third Report</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li value="second" class="select-li Second">
      <span class="caret second">&nbsp;</span>second
      <ul class="nested second">
        <li value="First Report">First Report</li>
        <li value="Second Report">Second Report</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: `.each(function (index) {})` method supports for indexer.

Comment: @Teemu `$(this)` doesn't do a DOM query, same element reference as in the each callback arguments. `$(selector).each(function(i,el){ el === this//true})`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your selector, use '.' for class query and `>` for children

Moreover, use `.attr()` to get the value attribute

```js
var phrase = {};
var inc = 1
$("#menu > li.select-li").each(function() {
  phrase[inc] = $(this).attr('value');
  inc++;
});

console.log(phrase)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="tab-pane fade show active">
    <ul class="end-info" id="menu">

      <li value="First" class="select-li First">
        <span class="caret First">&nbsp;</span>First</li>
      <ul class="nested First">
        <li value="First Report">First Report</li>
        <li value="Second Report">Second Report</li>
        <li value="Third Report">Third Report</li>
      </ul>
      <li value="second" class="select-li Second">
        <span class="caret second">&nbsp;</span>second</li>
      <ul class="nested second">
        <li value="First Report">First Report</li>
        <li value="Second Report">Second Report</li>
      </ul>
    </ul>
    <div>
</body>

</html>
```